# styling broken since Chrome 39

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Take a look at the following navigation
[image: Chrome 39 header]

As you see, the styling of the navigation is broken since Chrome 39. It works fine on Chrome 38 and any other modern browser.

The only thing I see that fixes the layout is setting the font-size of the  to any other size than 15px. But it should be 15px.

The same thing goes for the top navigation links, changing the font from 12px to 13px fixes that too.

Any ideas?

edit:
I've isolated the problem and found the fix. See my answer below

Comment: Are you just curious, or are you the developer of the Randstad site? In either case, I think you need to explain in more detail what goes wrong, and provide some (isolated) code to reproduce the problem, instead of coincidentally directing everybody to an employment agency. ;-)

Comment: @GolezTrol You are right, I didn't think about that. I'm the developer there. I'll try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the isolated problem here:
http://jsbin.com/nomavoluye/2/edit

Apperently `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` caused this problem, removing this fixed it